# Using Mutagen ID3 Tags to Update Cover Art in Spotify's Local Files

Tags: python, spotify, id3, local-files, mutagen

I was building my first project that edited the metadata of an mp3 file so that the upload process to Spotify's local files can be a lot easier.

Using the mutagen python library, my program edits the TIT2 (song name), TPE1 (artist name), and APIC (cover art) of an mp3 file. Thus far, the updates in the song name and artist name translate to the local files on Spotify but the cover art remains blank.

One way to solve this is to manually add artwork through apple music but I am trying to automate as much as possible while having as little interference as possible.

Is there any way I can get the cover art to load on my local files on Spotify through python? I.e - any libraries that might work?

EDIT: Fixed through using eyed3 instead of mutagen.